# Debugging SDK binaries in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Suppose I have an library that I distribute as a binary, SDK1, to a project, ProjectA.

Since I have the source code for the SDK, is there a way for me to debug the SDK binary in ProjectA  so I can step through the SDK code?

I am trying to step through the SDK code while running ProjectA.